# How to convert NSString to JSON by escaping all special characters using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json

I have created a function in order to make a perfect JSON string:

```
-(NSString *)NSStringToJson:(NSString *)str
{
    NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithString:str];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\\" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"\\/" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\b" withString:@"\\b" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\f" withString:@"\\f" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@"\\r" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@"\\t" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\{" withString:@"\\{" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    [s replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@"\\}" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
    return [NSString stringWithString:s];
}
```

**Problem**

The above function is not able to form the given below string to JSON string

```
üáñ~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[\]{}|;’:”,./<>?~
```

> {    "country": "233",    "email": "",    "first_name":
>   "üáñ~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]|;’:”,./<>?~",    "last_name": "",
>   "phone_mobile": "",    "token": "111"}

I am using [JSON online parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to validate the string and the parser is showing errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just ridiculous. Use `NSJSONSerialization`.

You are nowhere near converting everything that needs converting, and you are converting things that don't need converting. Unless your goal is to write a JSON serialiser that is better than existing ones, doing this by hand instead of using a class designed to do this for you is for mugs.

I can't quite see why you try to convert double quotes with two backslashes. And of course you don't handle backslashes in the string at all. That's the problem, you write your own buggy code instead of using a proper library. (Another problem is that you are writing buggy code, and I'd wager a bet that you haven't actually consulted the RFC containing the JSON standard).

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code if you are using `NSURLConnection`

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  {
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *output = [NSJSONSerialization
                            JSONObjectWithData:receivedData
                                       options:kNilOptions
                                        error:&error];
    NSLog(@"output : %@",output);
  }
```